# Stored Procedure doesn't work, manual update works fine - why?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So when executing the SQL below I get the following: String or binary data would be truncated.

```
EXEC sp_GoodsWelcomeNotification 'd84be19b-be86-4a38-958b-e6d786cc27db'
```

The stored procedure is as follow:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_GoodsWelcomeNotification](
@ItemGuid VARCHAR(50)
)

AS
DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(50), @ParentGuid VARCHAR(100)
    SET @ProductCode = 'SELECT Idx37 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6=' + @ItemGuid
    SET @ParentGuid = 'SELECT Idx134 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6=' + @ItemGuid

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO NotificationTable
    VALUES(650, @ProductCode, @ParentGuid, 'PENDING','','','Y','Y',@ItemGuid,0,'','')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

When I execute the insert statement manually it executes fine:

```
INSERT INTO NotificationTable
    VALUES(650, 'BV-TKM-0000068-02', '241c8abc-5f95-4c35-9405-d6adfc8e2f55', 'PENDING','','','Y','Y','d84be19b-be86-4a38-958b-e6d786cc27db',0,'','')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please check whether VARCHAR(50) assigned for @ItemGuid is sufficient or not. Keep it on higher side for safety.

Comment: you store your select into your values instead of execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is incorrect:

```
SET @ProductCode = 'SELECT Idx37 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6=' + @ItemGuid
SET @ParentGuid = 'SELECT Idx134 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6=' + @ItemGuid
```

I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT @ProductCode = Idx37 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6=@ItemGuid
SELECT @ParentGuid = Idx134 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6=@ItemGuid
```

You're assigning the `SELECT`statement to you variables, rather than the result of the select statements

Or a more simple query would be:

```
SELECT 
    @ProductCode = Idx37,
    @ParentGuid = Idx134
FROM 
    iwfAccountOpening 
WHERE 
    Idx1!='' 
    AND Idx6=@ItemGuid
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the same select statement for both variables, since the from and where clauses are the same. **edit** Did you just read my mind?!?

Comment: I would also add that column names like this makes my dizzy... I'm a fan of meaningful names :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_GoodsWelcomeNotification](
@ItemGuid VARCHAR(50)
)

AS
DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(50), @ParentGuid VARCHAR(100)
SET @ProductCode = (SELECT Idx37 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND      Idx6= @ItemGuid)
SET @ParentGuid = (SELECT Idx134 FROM iwfAccountOpening WHERE Idx1!='' AND Idx6= @ItemGuid)

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO NotificationTable
VALUES(650, @ProductCode, @ParentGuid,   'PENDING','','','Y','Y',@ItemGuid,0,'','')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```